# Inheritance concept: error:non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, inheritance

The code below gives a compile time error:`non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context.`
Could someone tell me where I've made a mistake? I'm new to programming so it would be great if you explain it step by step.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Dog{
int age;
String name;
public void BowBow(){
    System.out.println("Bow Bow I'm Dog1");
}
public  class Dog1 extends Dog{
    int age1;
    String name1;
    public void owow(){
        System.out.println("oow oow I'm Dog2");
    }
}
public class Dog2 extends Dog1{
    int age2;
    String name2;
    public void uhh(){
        System.out.println("uhh uhh I'm Dog3");
    }
}
public static void main(String [] args){
        Dog1 obj1 = new Dog1();
        Dog2 obj2 = new Dog2();
        Dog2 obj3 = new Dog2();
        obj1.age = 18;
        obj1.name = "Hugo";
        System.out.println("age:"+obj1.age);
        System.out.println("Name:"+obj1.name);
        obj2.age1 = 19;
        obj2.name1 = "Huxley";
        System.out.println("Age:"+obj2.age1);
        System.out.println("Name:"+obj2.name1);
        obj3.BowBow();
        obj3.owow();
        obj3.uhh();

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see `this` used anywhere

Comment: But i get this error when i compile this code

Comment: You're trying to refer to a non-static nested class from a static method. I doubt that nested classes are what you were trying to get, so you should probably move `Dog1`, etc. out of the `Dog` class

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that the `Dog1`, `Dog2` classes are non-static nested(inner) classes, and a non-static nested class in Java contains an implicit reference to an instance of the parent class. So to instantiate `Dog1`, you would need to instantiate `Dog` as well.

However, if you make `Dog1` a `static` class or perhaps even an `outer` class, then it will not need a reference to `Dog` and you would then be able to instantiate it directly in the static main method.

So you've got 3 options:

1)Make Dog1, Dog2 static inner classes, and then your code will run fine.

2)Make Dog1, Dog2 outer classes


3)Create the inner object within the outer object, in this manner:

`Dog1 obj1 = new Dog().new Dog1();`